# mongoose autoincrement counter per unique value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the two models, entity and post, and I'm trying to create an auto incremented counter on post for each unique entity:

```
//entity
var entitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    counter: Number,
});

//post
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    test: String,
    entity: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'entity'
    },
    ticketNumber: Number //this needs to auto increment starting at zero PER user, so entity A has a 1+, entity 2 has a 1+, etc
});
```

I can have a sequence on entity, check it every time I create a post and use it, but that could possibly have duplicates.

I found a post suggesting an even on pre post'save', but that wouldn't be unique to each entity, just unique overall.

Any way to get this working on the model itself / a better way of doing this?

Comment: See [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). Essentially you want to `$inc` the counter value on each entity by it's `_id`, returning that object with the "incremented" counter **before** you even assign that reference to the `Post` object you are creating. This is promise or callback chains depending on which coding style you are using. Bottom line is the `.findOneAndUpdate()` does the "increment" ( and possibly create ) on a search for say `"name"`, then returns the modified object with the `_id` reference you use in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package called  mongoose-auto-increment.

Your connection would look like this:

```
    var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');

    var connection = mongoose.connect('YOUR CONNECTION');

    autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
```

your Schema would look like this:

```
    var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        test: String,
        entity: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'entity'
        },
        ticketNumber: Number
    });

    postSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'NAME YOUR MODEL', field: 'ticketNumber', startAt: 0, incrementBy: 1 });
```

Comment: This auto increments everything, it does not have a different counter for each entity (Unless I'm doing it wrong)